# Is it possible to use destructuring to declare in less lines of code this decalarations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Is it possible to use destructuring to declare in less lines of code this decalarations?

```
const identification_type = this.phaseOneForm.controls.identification_type.value;
const identification_number =this.phaseOneForm.controls.identification_number.value;
const date_of_issue = this.phaseOneForm.controls.date_of_issue.value;
const date_of_birth = this.phaseOneForm.controls.date_of_birth.value;
const pep = this.phaseOneForm.controls.pep.value;
const us = this.phaseOneForm.controls.us.value;
const qualified_investor = this.phaseOneForm.controls.qualified_investor.value;
```

I tried:

```
const {
  value: identification_type,
  value: identification_number,
  value: date_of_issue,
  value: date_of_birth,
  value: pep,
  value: us,
  value: qualified_investor,
} = this.phaseOneForm.controls;
```

But does not work

Comment: You did everything right but need to use this syntax `identification_type: {value: identification_type},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax is not completely correct

```js
const {
    identification_type: {
        value: identification_type
    },
    identification_number : {
        value: identification_number 
    },
    date_of_issue: {
      value: date_of_issue
    },
    date_of_birth : {
        value: date_of_birth 
    },
    pep : {
        value: pep 
    },
    us : {
        value: us 
    },
    qualified_investor : {
        value: qualified_investor 
    }
} = this.phaseOneForm.controls;
```